# How do I convert two repeating for loops for my blackjack game into a single function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am creating a blackjack game and I am familiar with the rules of the game. But my conundrum lies elsewhere.
I am able to randomly append cards to computer and user. But for that purpose I have written the for loop twice. I want to just write a function for randomly assigning two **different** set of cards to the user and computer. I have included the code below for better understanding

```
import random
print("Welcome to Blackjack!")
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

def deal_cards():
  return random.choice(cards)


user_cards = []
for _ in range(2):
  card = random.choice(cards)
  if card in user_cards:
    continue
  else:
    user_cards.append(card)


computer_cards = []
for _ in range(2):
  card = random.choice(cards)
  if card in computer_cards:
    continue
  else:
    computer_cards.append(card)

print(user_cards)
print(computer_cards)
```

Comment: make a function that is just that loop and outputs the list? What's the issue

Comment: Read the documentation for the libaries you use. `random.choices(cards, k=2)` performs the "pick without reinsert" operation.

In any case, that's not the proper way to handle deck shuffling, you should use `random.shuffle` once and then `pop` cards from the list. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I was not sure how to go about it earlier but i tried just what you said erstwhile.

Comment: @Tordek woah I wasn't aware of something like this. But I still cannot wrap my head around thinking why would I use pop ? Like what are the ramifications if I don't use this method ?

Comment: As your code is written right now it is impossible to get a hand like `[10, 10]` even though 10 is 4 times on the list.

By using shuffle/pop you only have one deck that you shuffle and each time you deal a card you remove it from the deck, so they cannot repeat; but they can each show up once.

Comment: @Tordek woah. Thanks a lot I never thought of this edge case. Many thanks I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
def deal_hand():
    hand = []
    for _ in range(2):
        card = random.choice(cards)
        if card in hand:
            continue
        else:
            hand.append(card)
    return hand
```

and then

```
user_hand = deal_hand()
dealer_hand = deal_hand()
```

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for. I had used similar syntax but since I did not return hand I was getting an out put of none. Thanks a lot mate.